# django why cookie not sending to client browser?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, cookies

I properly setup cros. Trying to send cookie to client browser but don't know where I am doing mistake and cookie not going to client browser:

setting.py

```
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://*",
    "https://*",]

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    "http://*",
    "https://*",]

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
        "http://*",
        "https://*",

CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
```

my api code:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse,JsonResponse

 @api_view(["POST","GET"])
 def UserProfileAPI(request):
 if request.method == "POST":
            #...others code performing validation if success then allow user login 
    login(request, user)
    #refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
    #access_token = str(refresh.access_token)
    #refresh_token = str(refresh)

    serializers = AuthorProfileSerialzers(data=request.data)
   
    try:
        existing_profile=  AuthorProfile.objects.get(author = request.user)
    except:
        existing_profile = None
    if not existing_profile:  
        if serializers.is_valid():
            instance = serializers.save()
            instance.author = request.user
            instance.author_pic = request.data.get("profile_image")
            instance.save()

    response = HttpResponse('Cookie set successfully')
    # Set a cookie named 'my_cookie' with a value 'cookie_value'
    response.set_cookie('my_cookie', 'cookie_value', max_age=3600, path='/',samesite=None,secure=False)
    return response 
   # return Response({"detail":"sucess","jwt_token":access_token,"refresh_token":refresh_token}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I am receiving the 200 response from backend but don't know why cookie isn't sending to browser
[image]

Comment: Hi, it is not clear if you're trying to set a cookie to others that your server domain name, if so it is not possible to achieve the way you implement it. However, you may send cookie value via response and update your frontend code, so it picks it up.